# Java - IF statements with arrays

Tags: arrays, if-statement

I am creating an array that will add up its boundaries around it.

For example: In an array, say I have a value at [1][1]. I want to add up the boundaries(left, right, up, down) around that [1][1]. So the boundries would be [1][0],[0][1],[1][2],[2][1].. If the value is at [0][0], it will still look up and to the left but there are no spots there because it is already at 0. So it will copy whatever value is in [0][0] and use it for up and left.

I am trying to create a loop that will have an if statement that will check to see if there is an up, down, left or right and if there is then it will do .... If it doesnt then it will do...

How would I start the IF statement to see if there is left right up or down?

```
if(arrayName[row] < 0){
```

Thats where I am stuck on

Answer (score 0):

`if(coord == 0 || coord >= arrayName.length)`

It's often convenient to declare your array with an extra row (filled with 0) to avoid doing all those bounds checks. But I guess not if you want to add extra copies of the value instead.